# Group adjacent values

Tags: code-golf, subsequence

The task is to group adjacent values from collection and output it as a new aggregated collection.

Consider we have following input:

```
Sequence
Number      Value
========    =====
1           9
2           9
3           15
4           15
5           15
6           30
7           9
```

The aim is to enumerate over Sequence Numbers and check if the next element has the same value. If yes, values are aggregated and so, desired output is as following:

```
Sequence    Sequence
Number      Number
From        To          Value
========    ========    =====
1           2           9
3           5           15
6           6           30
7           7           9
```

Build a code with following assumptions:

- Sequence Numbers are already ordered in input table.
- There can be gaps in Sequence Numbers. If input contains gaps, output should contain gaps too. For example input `1 99\n2 99\n4 99\n6 99`, output will be `1 2 99\n4 4 99\n6 6 99`.
- Assume Value is type of integer.
- It can be a full program or just a function.
- This cruft `(Sequence Sequence\n` ... `======== ======== =====\n)` is not a part of output. Output format is not defined; there should be a delimeter between values and between rows, so anyone can distinguish values and rows.

It's an extend of my StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879197/linq-query-data-aggregation.

Comment: Should it be a full program with input/output or just a function?

Comment: Is all that cruft at the top (`Sequence    Sequence\n` ... `========    ========    =====\n`) part of the expected input and output? If not, can you please specify the expected formats?

Comment: @grc: I precised rules, thank you.

Comment: @dmckee: As above, I precised question, thx.

Comment: Regarding possible gaps in the sequence numbers: should the output also contain gaps? What would the desired output for "1 99\n2 99\n4 99\n6 99" be?

Comment: @Howard: Yes, output should also contain gaps as there must be continuity on Sequence Number; so for your input it will be: `1 2 99\n4 4 99\n6 6 99`.

Comment: What is the format of the input? If we're talking about a function, then can it take a data structure directly (in languages where that is applicable)? Can it also return a data structure?

Comment: @aditsu: There are no restrictions oninput/output format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## K, <strike>43</strike> 38

<strike>{d:(x;0N,x;y)@\:&~~':y;d[1]:(1_d 1),*|x;+d}</strike>

```
{a::*|x;+@[(x;{x,a};y)@\:&~~':y;1;1_]}
```

.

```
k){a::*|x;+@[(x;{x,a};y)@\:&~~':y;1;1_]}[1 2 3 4 5 6 7;9 9 15 15 15 30 9]
1 2 9 
3 5 15
6 6 30
7 7 9
```

## Explanation

The function takes two vectors, `x` and `y`, as input

`a::*|x` takes the last value of `x` and assigns it to `a`.

`&~~':y` returns a list of indices where the `y` vector changes:

```
k){&~~':y}[1 2 3 4 5 6 7;9 9 15 15 15 30 9]
0 2 5 6
```

`(x;{x,a};y)` creates a three element list containing

1) the `x` vector,

2) the function `{x,a}` which takes an input variable `x`(not to be confused with the `x` vector which was input into the original function) and appends `a`, and

3) the `y` vector

`(x;{x,a};y)@\:&~~':y` takes this three element list and applies the indices to each element
so that we return the `x` vector at those indices, the indices with `a` appended, and the `y` vector at those indices

```
k){b::*|x;(x;{x,b};y)@\:&~~':y}[1 2 3 4 5 6 7;9 9 15 15 15 30 9]
1 3 6 7
0 2 5 6 7
9 15 30 9
```

`@[(x;{x,a};y)@\:&~~':y;1;1_]` takes the matrix we've created and drops the first element of the second row.

```
k){b::*|x;@[(x;{x,b};y)@\:&~~':y;1;1_]}[1 2 3 4 5 6 7;9 9 15 15 15 30 9]
1 3  6  7
2 5  6  7
9 15 30 9
```

`+` then transposes the result

```
k){b::*|x;+@[(x;{x,b};y)@\:&~~':y;1;1_]}[1 2 3 4 5 6 7;9 9 15 15 15 30 9]
1 2 9 
3 5 15
6 6 30
7 7 9
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain how it works?

Answer (score 4):

### *Mathematica*, <s>40</s> 47 / 40

Updated to handle the new rules:

```
#~Riffle~{##}[[-1,1]]&@@@Split[#,#2-#=={1,0}&]&
```

Example of use:

```
#~Riffle~{##}[[-1,1]]&@@@Split[#,#2-#=={1,0}&]& @
  {{1, 9}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}, {4, 15}, {5, 15}, {6, 30}, {7, 9}, {12, 9}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 9}, {4, 5, 15}, {6, 6, 30}, {7, 7, 9}, {12, 12, 9}}
> ```

Or, since "There are no restrictions on input/output format":

```
#[[1,1]]|Last@#&/@Split[#,#2-#=={1,0}&]&
```

Which when used as above outputs:

> ```
> {1 | {3, 9}, 4 | {5, 15}, 6 | {6, 30}, 7 | {7, 9}, 12 | {12, 9}}
> ```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the magic of the left hand side, `#~Riffle~{##}[[-1, 1]] & @@@`.  (I already explained what SplitBy does.)

Comment: Does it consider the gaps as required? Try `d = {{1, 9}, {3, 9}, {4, 15}, {5, 15}, {6, 30}, {7, 9}}`

Comment: @belisarius there, now it does.

Comment: Ok, +1 then. Nice hack

Answer (score 3):

### J, <s>53</s> <s>48</s> 43

Explicit version (43 chars):

```
f=.4 :'|:(#&y,{.@:#&x)(1&,,:,&1)2(-.@=/\)x'
```

Tacit version (48 chars):

```
(|:@((#{.)~,{.@]#{:@[)[:(1&,,:,&1)2&(-.@=/\)@{:)
```

Ungolfed version:

```
(|:@(({.@[#~]),{:@[#~{.@])((1&,),:,&1)@(-.@(0&=)@(2&(-/\)@{:)))
```

Maybe not the best way, but had a lot of fun golfing it down.

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 f 9 9 15 15 15 30 9
   or
   (...) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7,:9 9 15 15 15 30 9
1 2  9
3 5 15
6 6 30
7 7  9
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 106

```
function(c){for(var n={f:1,t:1,v:c[0]},r=[n],i=1,t;t=c[i++];)t^n.v?r.push(n={f:i,t:i,v:t}):n.t++;return r}
```

If input as a global called `c` is okay, then **101**:

```
eval.bind(0,'for(var n={f:1,t:1,v:c[0]},r=[n],i=1,t;t=c[i++];)t^n.v?r.push(n={f:i,t:i,v:t}):n.t++;r')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 86

```
n=input()
for s,v in n:
 i=1
 while[s+i,v]in n:n.remove([s+i,v]);i+=1
 print s,s+i-1,v
```

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to run it (same as my answer)

Answer (score 1):

### APL 39

```
(p/n),((1⌽p)/n←⍎⍞),[1.1](p←1,2≠/v)/v←⍎⍞
```

The above takes screen input as the function runs via ←⍎⍞. If the vectors n and v are allowed to be predefined globals then the count reduces to 33:

```
(p/n),((1⌽p)/n),[1.1](p←1,2≠/v)/v
```

For n←1 2 3 4 5 6 7 and v←9 9 15 15 15 30 9

```
1 2  9
3 5 15
6 6 30
7 7  9
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 - 82

```
r=p=[]
for x,y in input():
 if[x-1,y]==p[1:]:p[1]=x
 else:p=[x,x,y];r+=[p]
print r
```

Example usage:

```
echo "[[1,9],[2,9],[3,15],[4,15],[5,15],[6,30],[7,9]]"|python2 values.py
[[1, 2, 9], [3, 5, 15], [6, 6, 30], [7, 7, 9]]
echo "[[1,99],[2,99],[4,99],[6,99]]"|python2 values.py
[[1, 2, 99], [4, 4, 99], [6, 6, 99]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript - 42

```
~(~@@.@{.~5$=\3$)=&{;)}{:*;@]p*~\.}if}/@]p
```

Examples:

```
echo "[[1 9][2 9][3 15][4 15][5 15][6 30][7 9]]"|ruby golfscript.rb values.gs
[1 2 9]
[3 5 15]
[6 6 30]
[7 7 9]

echo "[[1 99][2 99][4 99][6 99]]"|ruby golfscript.rb values.gs
[1 2 99]
[4 4 99]
[6 6 99]
```

Explanation:

It takes the first pair [a b], and puts b, a, a1=a and the rest of the array on the stack. Then for each pair [x y] it compares y with b and x with a1+1. If equal then discards [x y] and increments a1, else pops and remembers [x y], prints [a a1 b] and pushes y, x, x1=x. At the end it prints the last [x x1 y].

Answer (score 1):

#### GolfScript, 49/44 characters

```
~]2/{\.@.@~@~@=@@-)!&!{n\}*}*][n]%{.0=0=\-1=~]p}%
```

The solution takes input from STDIN and prints to STDOUT. If you transform the code into an expression working on lists it reduces to 44 characters.

```
{\.@.@~@~@=@@-)!&!{n\}*}*][n]%{.0=0=\-1=~]}%
```

Example:

```
1 9
2 9
3 15
4 15
5 15
6 30
7 9

[1 2 9]
[3 5 15]
[6 6 30]
[7 7 9]
```

This version does also work with gaps as required.

```
1 9
3 9
4 15
6 15
7 15

[1 1 9]
[3 3 9]
[4 4 15]
[6 7 15]
```